# Docker run, can not find jekyll installed

Tags: docker

On my gitlab server, I am running this docker command

```
sudo docker run --rm -it --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll1" jekyll/jekyll:4.0 jekyll new blog
```

I got

```
New jekyll site installed in /srv/jekyll/blog.
```

But I can not find it /srv

```
vagrant@gitlab:/srv$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 26 15:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Nov 27 10:26 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 26 15:54 gitlab-runner/
```

I omitted sys and proc mountpoints

```
├─/run                                tmpfs      tmpfs      rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=307336k,mode=755
│ ├─/run/lock                         tmpfs      tmpfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k
│ ├─/run/rpc_pipefs                   sunrpc     rpc_pipefs rw,relatime
│ ├─/run/user/1000                    tmpfs      tmpfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=307332k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000
│ └─/run/docker/netns/b15bf0ea5618    nsfs[net:[4026532209]]
│                                                nsfs       rw
├─/var/lib/lxcfs                      lxcfs      fuse.lxcfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other
├─/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d677b53723d5f2816bac4bcd7b1f3ca166f4f0cc4599dacae4cf72d922aaeb04/merged
│                                     overlay    overlay    rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/3Z6UMJAPHP7TYA5U634NXDYJXD:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/5GMF7Y
└─/vagrant                            vagrant    vboxsf     rw,nodev,relatime
```

I am also missing jekyll container

```
sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
bcb21149552c        gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   2 days ago          Up 47 minutes                           gitlab-runner
```

If I try to remove

```
vagrant@gitlab:~$ sudo docker run --rm -it --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" jekyll/jekyll:4.0 jekyll new blog
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux-musl]
          Conflict: /srv/jekyll/blog exists and is not empty.
                    Ensure /srv/jekyll/blog is empty or else try again with `--force` to proceed and overwrite any files.
```

Wher is my jekyll actually installed?

Comment: You have a typo. `--volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll1"` should be `--volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll"`. Please remove 1.

Comment: @leopal It doen't matter,I run command 5 times,the question is where is jekyll?

Comment: It matters. Image by default installs blog under `/srv/jekyll/blog`. Nothing is installed under `/srv/jekyll1` thus when you mount this path to your `PWD` nothing happens. Try `docker run --rm -it --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" jekyll/jekyll:4.0 jekyll new blog`.  This will install blog under your working dir and afterwards the container will normally exit as it has completed its purpose.

Comment: @leopal Take a look at my edit. It says that /srv/jekyll/blog exists.

Comment: Some things to try. Remove stopped containers `docker container prune` and then try again with an absolute path instead of `$PWD`. Ensure that your user has rw permission on that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things here.

You are using `ll` in your host, but `/srv/jekyll/blog` is **inside** the container.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the file if you want to view those. change the containerid which is currently running to check the container id `docker ps`

```
docker exec -it bcb21149552c /bin/bash
```

then

```
cd /srv/jekyll
ls -l
```

Comment: docker exec  bcb21149552c ls -l /srv/jekyll